# "использоваться" and "употреблять"

Tags: выбор-слова

What is the difference between "использоваться" and "употреблять"?

When do we use the first one and when the latter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`исполЬзоваться`** is a reflexive verb, which means it doesn't have a direct object (is intransitive) and denotes an action being experienced by the subject

> инструмент<sup>*subject*</sup> используется<sup>*predicate*</sup> в работе - a tool **is (being) used** in the works

**`употреблять`** is an active verb which can have an object (is transitive) and denotes an action being performed by the subject

> я<sup>*subject*</sup> употребляю<sup>*predicate*</sup> много чеснока<sup>*dir.object*</sup> - i **consume** a lot of garlic

The use cases of the verb **`исполЬзовать`** are identical to those of the the verb `to use`, and of the verb **`исполЬзоватьСЯ`** - to those of its past participle `to be used`.

**`Употреблять`** is mainly utilized to denote consumption (food, liquids, medicines, substances), usage of objects for specific purpose and/or accomplishment of a certain objective evident from the context or explicitly introduced with  prepositions `для`, `c целью`, as well as usage of words/language/vocabulary (as in `в общении с дамами я мат не употребляю`)

[This article](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) in the Wiktionary has a pretty exhaustive in my opinion  set of use case examples for the verb **`употреблять`**

Comment: +1. A very good answer covering it all. The only addition that can be made is  describing the existence of the verb "употреблять**ся**". "Использовать(ся)" and "употреблять(ся)" are practically two pairs of synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a feel of the difference in usage.

There is an intended diminutive in:

> Каждый человек необходимо приносит пользу, будучи употреблен на своем
>   месте.
>   https://www.inpearls.ru/665418

It has the touch of consumerism towards people, which was probably the intended pun.

---

Background: [Козьма Прутков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) is a collective pseudonym that coined satire and also abstruse and humorous aphorisms. The actual idea of the saying is apparently from Sun Tsu, the correct wording is:

> Каждый человек приносит пользу, когда занимается своим делом.